# How to create report(e.g. PDF,Excel,Word) in ASP.NET Core 1.0？

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to create report(e.g. PDF,Excel,Word) in ASP.NET Core 1.0,
but NPOI and OpenXML is not support ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue for .NET Core support for OpenXML (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/65). Some work has to be done before it is ready. Someone who had your demand as well ported it to .NET Core and published his project on GitHub (https://github.com/xrkolovos/Open-XML-SDK-for-NET-Platform-Standard). I have not tried it myself, but it may be worthwile to try.

**UPDATE**:

Current releases of OpenXML support .NET Core. Therefore the second GitHub project is obsolete now.

Comment: In the latest version of Open XML SDK, you don't need for using the second project and it supports .Net Core projects.

Answer (score 2):

For PDF **PdfReport.Core** could be a solution. I can confirm that it works under **netcoreapp1.1**. It also should be able to export to Excel, XML and CSV (NOT tested by me).

Please check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023039/1719087

Answer (score 1):

There is a CI build that works with .Net Core 1.1 at

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

the specific nuget package is at this feed:

https://dotnet.myget.org/F/open-xml-sdk/api/v3/index.json

Answer (score 0):

If your application is fine to run on windows only, then using ASP.NET Core with the full .net framework let you use NPOI and OpenXML. With this approach you can start now with the new Microsoft web framework in the hope that NPOI or OpenXML will support .NET Core in the near future.

Comment: Thank for you answer.My application run on linux system,so I can not use NPOI and OpenXML.